# IONIC 2 Globalization Plugin error

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2, globalization

i am doing an ionic 2 app with angular 2 and typescript and i had to use the globalization plugin offered by ionic/Cordova. The plugin always encounters an error when determining preferred language in the second time the app loads.

So the error scenario is like this: I change my phone's language to French from English and run my app. The app works flawlessly and the plugin detects i am using french language. i close the app and reopen it again then the plugin detects an error and catches it then displays it in a form of an alert.

This happens all the time.

here is the code i use to detect language :

```
let ln='';
      this.globalization.getPreferredLanguage()
        .then(res => {ln =res.value;
          console.log(ln);
          if(ln.substring(0,2) ==='fr'){
            this.translate.setDefaultLang('fr');
            this.translate.reloadLang('fr');
            localStorage.setItem("lang","1");
          }else{
            if(ln.substring(0,2)==="en"){
              this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
              this.translate.reloadLang('en');
              localStorage.setItem("lang","2");
            }else{
              this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
              this.translate.reloadLang('en');
              localStorage.setItem("lang","2");
            }
          }

        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
          this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
          this.translate.reloadLang('en');
          localStorage.setItem("lang","2");
          let altert= this.AlertC.create({
            title: "Language selection problem" ,
            message: "We have encountered an error in identifying your preferred language, so we put it to english as default.",
            buttons: [
              {
                text: 'OK',
                handler: () => {
                  console.log('Cancel clicked');
                }
              },
            ]
          });

          altert.present();
        });
```

Any ideas what the problem could be ?

Comment: The code is called after platform is ready in the app.component.ts

Comment: Constructor, and it is called after the platform is ready, so the globalization plugin i am using is ready to be used

Comment: Yes everytime the app is opened

Comment: show me the error output

Comment: `console.log(e);` what is the output of this?